# Does MrBean module still automatically support dynamically implementing simple interfaces when deserializing?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey

When converting from Jersey1 client to Jersey2 client (with jackson 2.8.6), I now get a mapping exception when trying to read my interface

```
WebTarget resource = helper.resource(path);
if(schedule != null) resource = resource.queryParam("schedule", schedule);
return resource.request().get(new GenericType<MyInterface>(){});

Caused by: javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.mycompany.MyInterface: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```

the old client code looked like this:

```
WebResource resource = helper.resource(path);
if(schedule != null) resource = resource.queryParam("schedule", schedule);
try
{
    return resource.get(new GenericType<MyInterface>(){});
}
catch(UniformInterfaceException e)
{
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getResponse().getEntity(String.class));
}
```

in both cases, all i did with the client object mapper was:

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new MrBeanModule());
```

is dynamic instantiation of interfaces gone now? If not, what additional configuration steps need to be performed to get it working?

(our dependencies are a bit of a mess, so i think i was using Jersey 1.6 with Jackson 1.9.8)

EDIT:
as another example of the previous behavior we relied upon, see http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/08/entry_459.html where there is a simple interface with no annotations

Answer (score 1):

i think i found it after a lot of blood, sweat, and tears.

i found that the ObjectMapper i had configured was actually not the one that was being used.

Jersey1

```
clientConfig.getSingletons().add(new JacksonJsonProvider(objectMapper));
Client client = new Client(urlConnectionClientHandler, clientConfig);
```

JAXRS2 (what did not work)

```
 clientConfig.register(new JacksonJsonProvider(objectMapper));
 Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(cc);
```

i found that the component creating the ObjectMapper that was ACTUALLY being used was a Jackson**Jaxb**JsonProvider and that registering it with the ClientConfig did not work, but registering it on the client did.

JAXRS2 (what did work)

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(cc);
    client.register(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider(objectMapper, JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.DEFAULT_ANNOTATIONS));
```